# transform distinct row values to different columns with corresponding rows using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pivot, rdd, transpose, flatmap

I'm new to Pyspark and trying to transform data

Given dataframe

```
Col1
A=id1a A=id2a B=id1b C=id1c B=id2b
D=id1d A=id3a B=id3b C=id2c
A=id4a C=id3c
```

Required:

```
A         B        C
id1a     id1b     id1c
id2a     id2b     id2c
id3a     id3b     id3b
id4a     null     null
```

I have tried pivot, but that gives first value.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible sample of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I don't know the full picture, but the data format seems to be strange. If nothing can be done at the data source, then some collects, pivots and joins will be needed. Try this.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
test = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A=id1a A=id2a B=id1b C=id1c B=id2b',1),('D=id1d A=id3a B=id3b C=id2c',2),('A=id4a C=id3c',3)],schema=['col1','id'])
tst_spl = test.withColumn("item",(F.split('col1'," ")))
tst_xpl = tst_spl.select(F.explode("item"))
tst_map = tst_xpl.withColumn("key",F.split('col','=')[0]).withColumn("value",F.split('col','=')[1]).drop('col')
#%%
tst_pivot = tst_map.groupby(F.lit(1)).pivot('key').agg(F.collect_list(('value'))).drop('1')
#%%
tst_arr = [tst_pivot.select(F.posexplode(coln)).withColumnRenamed('col',coln) for coln in tst_pivot.columns]  

tst_fin = reduce(lambda df1,df2:df1.join(df2,on='pos',how='full'),tst_arr).orderBy('pos')

tst_fin.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+
|pos|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  0|id3a|id3b|id1c|id1d|
|  1|id4a|id1b|id2c|null|
|  2|id1a|id2b|id3c|null|
|  3|id2a|null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+----
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way , however an approach is  splitting the column on spaces to create array of the entries and then using higher order functions(spark 2.4+) to split on the `'='` for each entry in the splitted array .Then explode and create 2 columns one with the id and one with the value. Then we can assign a row number to each partition and groupby then pivot:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 = (df.withColumn("Col1",F.split(F.col("Col1"),"\s+")).withColumn("Col1",
             F.explode(F.expr("transform(Col1,x->split(x,'='))")))
        .select(F.col("Col1")[0].alias("cols"),F.col("Col1")[1].alias("vals")))

from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("cols").orderBy("cols")
final = (df1.withColumn("Rnum",F.row_number().over(w)).groupBy("Rnum")
         .pivot("cols").agg(F.first("vals")).orderBy("Rnum"))
```

---

```
final.show()

+----+----+----+----+----+
|Rnum|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|id1a|id1b|id1c|id1d|
|   2|id2a|id2b|id2c|null|
|   3|id3a|id3b|id3c|null|
|   4|id4a|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

---

this is how `df1` looks like after the transformation:

```
df1.show()
+----+----+
|cols|vals|
+----+----+
|   A|id1a|
|   A|id2a|
|   B|id1b|
|   C|id1c|
|   B|id2b|
|   D|id1d|
|   A|id3a|
|   B|id3b|
|   C|id2c|
|   A|id4a|
|   C|id3c|
+----+----+
```